# Should I accept removing thanks edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Someone has been suggesting a lot of edits regarding simply removing "thanks in advance" from the post. Should I accept or reject? I've always accepted, but I am not sure if I did the right thing.

Comment: I think editing 5-year-old questions just to remove "Thanks" is excessive. ELL is not Stack Overflow, many SO users view "thanks in advance" as being fluff, irrelevant and distracting. Personally, I much prefer politeness to "gimme the answer" questions, and don't find "thanks in advance" objectionable, as long as the question has some meat on the bones, so to speak.

Comment: The choice is yours, if you find the edit is so trivial that it does not improve the post, you can reject it. If you agree pleasantries are best omitted, approve the suggested edit.

Comment: You should make that an answer @Mari-LouA, it'a quite helpful!

Comment: @DialFrost You mean me? If you take a look on my edits, you'll see that I always include the line "deleted thanks - https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/behavior - Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat." You can click into the link. "If you use signatures, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat, they will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers." - this is one of the most important sentences in it.

Comment: @DialFrost But note that I don't delete every post with thanks. If the question only contains one to three lines, I won't delete it, however, if the question is long, I'll delete it.

Comment: @DialFrost Actually, I learned to delete thanks from **you**! Because sometimes I see that when you edit posts, you'll delete thanks and after searching on the internet, I found the link I gave you in the earlier comments.

Comment: Also see [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1118/150280) answer about whether or not to accept minor edits on posts.

Comment: @Eden0516 quick tip, you don't have to delete thanks from old posts that are >1 month old, it doesnt do much good, newer posts are fine

Comment: @Eden0516 please read Glorfindel's answer

Comment: @DialFrost It's not about the age of the post, it's to reduce noise. Like to edit typos and grammar mistakes, no matter how old is the post.

Comment: I know, but i guess just make more improvements to the post e.g. formatting (until you reach 2k rep then you're free!) @Eden0516

Comment: @DialFrost There are different discussions about whether or not to approve the edit of deleting thanks. If you look at [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1113/minor-edits-on-posts-should-we-accept-them/1118#1118) answer, and [Glorfindel's answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5696/150280), you'll find that they contradict. And also have a look at the official document in my previous documents. Why do you reject my suggested edit?

Comment: @DialFrost And [this](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1364/150280) answer too. By the way, we don't have a problem with "too many suggested edits." on this site. Maybe in Stack Overflow, but not here.

Comment: @DialFrost What's more, the system already have a solution about "too many suggested edits". A user can only have 5 pending edits, so there's no problem. Please explain why you reject my suggested edits.

Comment: Bumping  > 2-year old posts just to remove a "thanks" is one cheap and easy way of earning rep I suppose. And when the zealous editor does have 2k they are free to edit as many posts as they like!!  15 posts bumped to the homepage. Argghhh!

Comment: As Mari-LouA has mentioned @Eden0516, you are bumping old posts to the homepage, so I rejected any old posts you edited

Comment: @DialFrost If you really don't want old posts appear in the homepage, go tell the community bot.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Asking me to edit my posts to add attributions made about 10 posts bumped to the homepage. "Argghhh!"

Comment: @DialFrost If you have never edited old posts more than two years old, then reject the edit. If not, don't tell me not to edit old posts.

Comment: @Eden0516 bumping ten posts on one single day is a reasonable limit. Try to find other ways of improving a post if you *must* edit out ["thank in advance"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22thank+in+advance%22).

Comment: @Mari-LouA https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268716/is-it-okay-to-edit-old-posts-that-have-been-inactive-for-months

Comment: @Mari-LouA Bumping ten posts one single day is a reasonable limit, but bumping fifteen post is not?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sometimes there's only one problem. Editing minor edits is okay, and editing old posts is okay too, according to the links I included in the earlier comments.

Comment: and there's roughly [220 questions with "thanks in advance"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3A+question++%22thanks+in+advance%22) I think you'll find a few users who will find 15 posts bumped ***daily*** on the homepage wearisome. ELL doesn't have that many new questions coming in that will push those edited posts away.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Even it'll bump on the homepage, it's still important to reduce noise and edit them.

Comment: Just a quick pointer, once you get 2k you can edit as much as you want (not too excessively cuz u will still bump the question pg.) But atm just try to make other improvements :) @Eden0516

Comment: @DialFrost If you can't listen any word I say, I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: I am listening, my point is you are not considering the people that regularly check the home page, and all they see is a bunch of old posts, so dont do it too much @Eden0516. Its being inconsiderate

Comment: @DialFrost We can't made old post better but not make it appear from the homepage.

Comment: @DialFrost If you don't want old posts to appear in the homepage, tell this site to throw away the badges Excavator and Archaeologist.

Comment: Related Discussions: [Rejecting edits that do not improve question. A question of degree](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5607/9161) / [ELL policy re. salutations and thank-you's in questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3211/9161) / [How helpful is it to add "Hope this is helpful!" to an ELL answer?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1367/9161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153076/295232) is some guidance from Meta Stack Exchange (posted mainly with Stack Overflow in mind, but relevant here as well):

> All you did was remove `thanks` from posts, leaving other problems in place. Such edits are too minor and clog up the queue.
>
> When making an edit suggestion, please improve the whole post, and not only remove the 'thank you'.
>
> Generally, count on edit suggestions that only touch one small aspect to be rejected.  Note that the *too minor* rejection reason states this unequivocally:
>
> > This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive
> > improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.
>
> Users with editing rights (more than 2000 reputation) can edit "thanks" out without the hassle of the suggested edits queue. The point is that we don't want to burden the queue with small trivial edits and waste reviewers' time.